# JSON output from the page

Tags: asp.net, json

I am developing an ASP.NET website in which based on certain logic, I am getting the output in a specific format on `http://localhost/menu.aspx?callback=example`

On the above URL, I get the output in a specific format `foo({"1":"Jeff","2":"Mic","5":"Mark"});` using this small code.

```
outputText += Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(0));
for (Int32 i = 1; i < k.Length; i++)
{
    outputText += "," + Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i));
}
//
outputText += "}" +");";

Response.Write(outputText);
```

The full code of `menu.aspx.cs` is putup here. http://pastebin.com/dxbNmais

But this the output in html form on `menu.aspx` page. But my requirement is that the http answer must be json too. Please help in getting this JSON output. Not only that I I haven't tried JSON earlier but I am not too much a pro in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: Where do I have to write this?

Comment: Anywhere in the method, just do it right after Response.Write(outputText);

Comment: Just, that's it!? What's with all those scary web services which I find when I searched on Google ?

Comment: @Chrise: When I add this line `Response.ContentType = "application/json" to my method and then type the address of the page, it starts asking to save that menu.aspx page like I downloaded it. Here's the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/4ZdTt.jpg

Answer (score 2):

add `Response.End();` after `Response.Write(..`

That should do.